# Assiging values to rows

Tags: r

So i am working on this data set which is a csv file.
mydata= 
name school  total_consumption
ram  abc     15
ram1 abcd    16
ram2 abcde   17
ram3 abcdef  18
ram4 acb     19
ram5 acbe    20

Now i want to sort the whole data in descending order and then assign segment such as s1, s2 etc. The no of segment is taken from the user as an input.So suppose user inputs 2 there will be 2 segments. Now the total no of rows will be divided by 2 and then first half will be segment 1 and second half will be segment 2.

segment val =2 
output  segemnt
20       s1
19       s1 
18       s1
17       s2
16       s2
15       s2

here is my code :

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library (hts)

setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/r")
mydata <- read.csv("read1.csv")

mydata$newcolumn <- NA

temp1 <- mydata[order(mydata$fy_vol, decreasing = TRUE),]

nrow(temp1)
row <- nrow(temp1)

readinteger <- function()
{ 
n <- readline(prompt="Enter number of quant: ")
n <- as.integer(n)
if (is.na(n)){
n <- readinteger()
}
return(n)
}

q <- readinteger()
nrow(temp1)
row <- nrow(temp1)
```

Comment: There is no example data that I can use to do what are you getting at. The questions is not clearly defined. Your code has mistakes. For eg. the order statment should have data$total_consumption instead of data$fy_vol.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has too many issues. Please read up on "how make a great reproducible example".The following set of codes should let you do what you are getting at.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library (hts)

setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/r")
mydata <- read.csv("read1.csv")

col1 <- c('ram1','ram2','ram3','ram4','ram5','ram6')
col2 <- c('abc','abcd','abcde','abcdef','abcdefg','abcdefgh')
col3 <- c(15:20)

mydata <- data.frame(name = col1, school = col2, total_consumption = 
col3)                 

mydata$newcolumn <- NA

temp1 <- mydata[order(mydata$total_consumption, decreasing = TRUE),]

nrow(temp1)
row <- nrow(temp1)

readinteger <- function()
{ 
n <- readline(prompt="Enter number of quant: ")
n <- as.integer(n)
if (is.na(n)){
n <- readinteger()
}
return(n)
}

q <- readinteger()
nrow(temp1)
row <- nrow(temp1)

#calculate the size of split based on if the entry is odd or even. 
seg1 <- ifelse(row %% q == 0,row/2,row/2-0.5) 

temp1$newcolumn[1:seg1] <- "s1"

temp1$newcolumn[seg1:row] <- "s2"
```